# I'm getting an error saying I've entered too many arguments in excel

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I am trying to do a calculation on the fiscal year expenditure based on whether the contract ends within the fiscal year or if it starts within the fiscal year, then determine the number of months and multiply it by the monthly rate but I keep getting an error saying "too many arguments" I don't think I'm at 64 arguments but I'm a sometimes excel user here is the nested IF statement:

```
=IF([@[Contract End Date]]>=43190,[@[Annual Rate]],
IF([@[Role Start Date]]<42826,(((YEAR("2018-3-31")-YEAR([@[Role Start Date]]))*12+MONTH("2018-3-31")-MONTH([@[Role Start Date]]))*[@[Monthly Rate]])),
IF([@[Contract End Date]]<43190,(((YEAR([@[Contract End Date]])-YEAR("2017-4-1"))*12+MONTH([@[Contract End Date]])-MONTH("2017-4-1"))*[@[Monthly Rate]])))
```

Comment: `If` statements take a max of 3 arguments each. You've got more than that if Excel is complaining about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a `)` in the wrong place, that was closing the second IF before the third IF:

```
=IF([@[Contract End Date]]>=43190,[@[Annual Rate]],
IF([@[Role Start Date]]<42826,(((YEAR("2018-3-31")-YEAR([@[Role Start Date]]))*12+MONTH("2018-3-31")-MONTH([@[Role Start Date]]))*[@[Monthly Rate]]),
IF([@[Contract End Date]]<43190,(((YEAR([@[Contract End Date]])-YEAR("2017-4-1"))*12+MONTH([@[Contract End Date]])-MONTH("2017-4-1"))*[@[Monthly Rate]]))))
```

Comment: thank you very much, now it's not recognizing when the role start date is earlier than March 31, 2018, and only returning the annual rate, what am I missing: =IF([@[Contract End Date]]>=43190,[@[Annual Rate]],
IF([@[Role Start Date]]<43190,(((YEAR("2018-3-31")-YEAR([@[Role Start Date]]))*12+MONTH("2018-3-31")-MONTH([@[Role Start Date]]))*[@[Monthly Rate]]),
IF([@[Contract End Date]]<43190,(((YEAR([@[Contract End Date]])-YEAR("2017-4-1"))*12+MONTH([@[Contract End Date]])-MONTH("2017-4-1"))*[@[Monthly Rate]]))))

Comment: That is new question and needs a new post.  Please include mocked up data and expected output along with the formula.  It is not possible to know without seeing the data. @user3112504